# Why does Data Factory Pipeline scheduled trigger sometimes gets offset?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have some scheduled daily running pipelines.
Sometimes the scheduled trigger start time [Run start time] gets offset by few seconds [1s to 5s].
This is happening to all the pipelines having the same trigger.
Some of pipes use IR and some of them don't.

Trying to understand why it's happening.

[Ex. Pipeline trigger offset by 1 second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdSll.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ashwin, yes this happens sometimes maybe due to a lag / latency between a trigger to start and actual start of a pipeline just like you clicking a button and time taken by the event behind that button to occur

But this does not hamper the execution of your pipeline